I can't pull a file affected by skip-worktree
I'm having issues with git and I don't understand how I am supposed to make it work
I firstly wanted to put a .gitignore file in the repository to prevent devs to push their modifications of a file.
But when the file gets changed in remote, the pull it and the file gets tracked, so the .gitignore becomes useless (tell me if I'm wrong)
So I tried git update-index --skip-worktree ./.vscode/settings.json
This works well, it is impossible to commit the file.
But, when I updated it in remote, and pull, this creates an error asking to commit my changes
(only this file got changed, and as I cannot commit it, I can't pull)
I guess I didn't understand well how it is supposed to work.
How can I prevent devs to push modifications on a file, but allow them to pull changes on it?

Does this answer your question? How to manage configuration files when collaborating?

Nope, but this one does Handling changes to files with --skip-worktree from another branch. This looks good but requires too much manipulation to make it easy to use. I'm searching an other easier way to do it

If there is a way to change TortoiseGit bash scripts to automatically unskip / stash / pull / pop stash / skip each time we pull or merge it would be awesome. But I didn't find anything about changing TortoiseGit scripts yet

also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore
If a file was already tracked, on top of adding it to .gitignore you need to remove it from the tracked files in your repo.

The proper way to handle this is that when developers make "personal" changes to .vscode/settings.json1 that should not be propagated out of the repository, then those changes should be checked in as temporary commits.
That way developers can maintain their own local modifications (for instance cSpell.words entries for extension Code Spell Checker) while having no problem receiving upstream changes (e.g. tslint.exclude, html.format.wrapAttributes, etc).

1 Or any other file.

That's the idea I got too :) I am working on a script that will stash changes, merge then pop the stash. I wanted to make something that won't generate errors while merging but it looks like it's not possible

You will be much better of if you stop using git stash and instead just use normal, temporary commits instead. Then you are less likely to get into trouble and avoid the dangerous, complicated quirks that stash have.
